# Stuck on a basic OpenGL program

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to create a sample program that can be used as a test harness for OpenGL. The one I have so far seems to work, but it seems that the MVP matrix passed via the uniform variable MVPMatrix is ignored. When I added code to read the uniform back and check that it was actually updating properly, I get an invalid operation error when doing so and I can't see why - what's going on?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sdl/SDL.h>
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/mesh.h>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <sdl/SDL_image.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <vector>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/mesh.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>
#include <assimp/vector3.h>

using namespace std;


void checkGLShaderStatus(GLuint id, GLuint thingToCheck, bool shader) {
    GLint ret;
    if (shader) glGetShaderiv(id, thingToCheck, &ret); else glGetProgramiv(id, thingToCheck, &ret);

    // If there was an error
    if (ret == GL_FALSE) {
        // Print it out, then halt
        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
        GLchar *shaderErrorLog = (GLchar*)malloc(sizeof(GLchar)*(maxLength + 1));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, maxLength, &maxLength, shaderErrorLog);
        shaderErrorLog[maxLength] = '\0';
        cout << shaderErrorLog;
        free(shaderErrorLog);
        int junk;
        cin >> junk;

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

GLuint buildShader(const GLchar **source, GLuint length, GLenum type) {
    // Create the shader
    GLuint shaderId = glCreateShader(type);
    // Upload source code
    glShaderSource(shaderId, length, source, NULL);
    // Compile the shader
    glCompileShader(shaderId);
    // See how the compilation went
    checkGLShaderStatus(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, true);
    return shaderId;
}

void checkGL(string stage) {
    GLuint error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        cout << "OpenGL broke..";
        switch (error) {
        case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
            cout << "Invalid Enum";
            break;
        case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
            cout << "Value out of range";
            break;
        case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
            cout << "Invalid operation";
            break;
        case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:
            cout << "Incomplete framebuffer";
            break;
        case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
            cout << "Out of memory";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Oh boy, did it break..";
        }
        cout << " (" << stage << ")" << endl;
        int junk;
        cin >> junk;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG | IMG_INIT_PNG) == -1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene *importedScene = importer.ReadFile("Table.3ds",aiProcess_Triangulate);
    if (importedScene == nullptr) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    aiMesh *theMesh = importedScene->mMeshes[0];
    if (theMesh == nullptr) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    cout << "I imported a mesh with " << theMesh->mNumVertices << " vertices and " << theMesh->mNumFaces << " faces! " << endl;

    SDL_Window *win = nullptr;
    win = SDL_CreateWindow("My even more awesome SDL/OGL program", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == nullptr) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    SDL_Renderer *ren = nullptr;
    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (ren == nullptr) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);
    if (context == nullptr) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    glewInit();

    int attrib_vPosition = 0;
    const GLchar *vertexShaderSource = { "#version 430 core\n"
        "layout (location=0) in vec4 vPosition;"
        "uniform mat4 MVPMatrix;"
        "void main() {"
        "  gl_Position = MVPMatrix * vPosition;"
        "}"};
    GLuint vertexShader = buildShader(&vertexShaderSource, 1, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    checkGL("compiling vertex shader");

    const GLchar *fragShaderSource = { "#version 430 core\n"
        "out vec4 fColor;"
        "void main() {"
        "  fColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
        "}"
    };
    GLuint fragmentShader = buildShader(&fragShaderSource, 1, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    checkGL("compiling fragment shader");

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    checkGLShaderStatus(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, false);
    checkGL("Linking shader");

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    //glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    //glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    checkGL("Running shader");

    GLint MVPlocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "MVPMatrix");
    checkGL("Getting uniform location");
    glm::mat4 mvpMatrix(0.1f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPlocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvpMatrix));
    checkGL("Setting uniform");

    GLint testLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "MVPMatrix[0][0]");
    checkGL("Getting uninform test cell location");
    GLfloat testfloat;
    glGetUniformfv(shaderProgram, testLocation, &testfloat);
    checkGL("Reading uniform");
    if (testfloat != mvpMatrix[0][0]) {
        cout << "Uniform setting did not sink in..";
    }

    GLuint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    checkGL("Creating VAO");

    GLfloat vertices[3][3] = { { -0.9f, -0.9f, 0.f }, { 0.85f, -0.9f, 0.f }, { -0.9f, 0.85f, 0.f } };
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    int vertexDataSize = 9;
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((void *)(0)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    checkGL("creating VBO");

    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexDataSize);
    glFlush();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);

    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;

    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would have been helpful if you told us *which operation* failed with an invalid operation error.

Comment: With regard to your scaling problem, I think that `gl_Position` was a predefined `varying` in older versions of GLSL, but not in the (modern) version you are using via `#version`.  Try an explicit `varying` variable for the transformed position?

Comment: I've just tried that - I get an error that "varying is deprecated"! Looking at http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL) it says that gl_Position is defined as part of an out block called gl_PerVertex. I tried copying that out block explicitly into the vertex shader, and then declaring the gl_Position component of it as "out" as well, but this still didn't work - there were no errors compiling the shader, but the matrix was still ignored.

Comment: Just spotted a potential problem - the positions being loaded are vec3s, not vec4s, or is the homogenous coordinate added automatically?

Comment: Just to be sure, the triangle is being rendered at full scale, no matter what matrix you load into the uniform?

Comment: That's right. I even tried putting an IF statement into the shader to test if MVPMatrix[0][0] was 1.0 and to collapse all the vertices to 0,0,0,0 if so. This worked - if the matrix is set to the identity, nothing appears, but if the matrix is set to non-identity the triangle appears.. but still isn't scaled.

Comment: Ah, GOT IT! It was actually mentioned in another question.. when glm creates a matrix it sets everything on the leading diagonal to the specified value, EVEN THE HOMOGENOUS COORDINATE, which neutralizes the effect of scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `glGetUniformfv(... glGetUniformLocation(... "MVPMatrix[0][0]"))`.  The documentation says

> `glGetUniformLocation` returns an integer that represents the location of a specific uniform variable within a program object. name must be a null terminated string that contains no white space. ***name* must be an active uniform variable name** in *program* **that is not** a structure, an array of structures, or **a subcomponent of a vector or a matrix**.

And

> `glGetUniform` returns in *params* the value(s) of the specified uniform variable. The type of the uniform variable specified by *location* determines the number of values returned. If the uniform variable is defined in the shader as a boolean, int, or float, a single value will be returned. If it is defined as a vec2, ivec2, or bvec2, two values will be returned. If it is defined as a vec3, ivec3, or bvec3, three values will be returned, and so on. To query values stored in uniform variables declared as arrays, call `glGetUniform` for each element of the array. To query values stored in uniform variables declared as structures, call `glGetUniform` for each field in the structure. **The values for uniform variables declared as a matrix will be returned in column major order.**

Your uniform variable `uniform mat4 MVPMatrix;` is declared as [a matrix type](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_%28GLSL%29#Matrices), not [an array](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_%28GLSL%29#Arrays) and you will retrieve the entire 4x4 matrix at once (just like you set it in a single operation).  Try

```
GLfloat testfloat[16];
glGetUniformfv(shaderProgram, MVPLocation, testfloat);
```

---

Another problem is here:

```
GLfloat vertices[3][3] = { { -0.9f, -0.9f, 0.f }, { 0.85f, -0.9f, 0.f }, { -0.9f, 0.85f, 0.f } };
int vertexDataSize = 9;
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexDataSize);
```

You don't have 9 vertices, only 3.

Comment: Thanks! There's still an underlying problem though, which is the reason I tried to read the matrix back in the first place - it has no effect. Whatever value is along the leading diagonal of the matrix, the triangle is not scaled, and I can't see why.

Comment: One question (problem) per question.  Here you had a question about how to read back the value of your uniform, which is now solved, correct?  The failure to scale was the rationale for reading back the uniform, but not the problem you described here.  I suggest that you ask a new question focused on the scaling, showing the output you got and the output you expected.  Feel free to link between the questions.  The new one can say that you did indeed verify the uniform contents, see this question for details.  And this one can be edited to...

Comment: say that you now can read back the uniform and can find nothing to explain the lack of scaling, which you've asked about over at (new question).

Comment: Ah, sorry. I asked them together because I thought they were related - if the matrix was somehow failing to install, that would be a good reason why there was an operation error reading it back.